# SQL Server : Bit Column Not Yielding Results

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

The following query yields 6 results:

```
SELECT ATTACHMENT_ID,
       /* Somme other columns */
       THUMBNAIL_EXIST,
       CASE isnull ((SELECT TOP 1 EMAIL_ID
                     FROM   EMAILS_ATTACHMENTS
                     WHERE  ATTACHMENT_ID = vwFILES_ATTACHMENTS.ATTACHMENT_ID), '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000')
         WHEN '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' THEN '0'
         ELSE '1'
       END AS SENT_ATTACHMENT,
       CASE File_ext
         WHEN '.pdf' THEN 'true'
         ELSE 'false'
       END AS 'enablecheck',
       CASE VISIBLE_TO_CLIENT
         WHEN '1' THEN '/FACTS/App_Themes/SugarClassic/images/check_inline.gif'
         ELSE '/FACTS/App_Themes/SugarClassic/images/close_inline.gif'
       END AS 'VISIBLE_TO_CLIENT_PATH'
FROM   vwFILES_ATTACHMENTS
WHERE  ( 1 = 1 )
       AND ( PARENT_TYPE = 'Files' )
       AND ( PARENT_ID = '55e52006-ce85-4781-b6f9-00b68c04d62f' )
       AND ( DELETED = 0 )
ORDER  BY DATE_ENTERED DESC
```

I modified the `DELETED` column on one row changing it from `False` to `True`. When I try to search for `DELETED = 1` instead of `DELETED = 0`, the search yields no results.

Why is the one row that I changed not showing up? I only get 5 results when I run my `DELETED = 0` query (above). The 6th result is not retrieved until I search specifically for it's `ATTACHMENT_ID`.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Maybe in your view you have TOP 5?

Comment: How do I check for that?  It's not in the query.

Comment: Did you update using this view? Or did you update the table directly? It might be possible that the new record is not meeting search criteria of the view as well as the where clause as mentioned above in query.

Comment: I am using MSSQL Server Management Studio and I updated it via the grid screen (not via query).  Is there a difference?

Comment: Can you show View creation script?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan:  I am sorry but I am not sure how to retrieve that for you.  I am new to this software.

Comment: Don't use the grid to update data. Here are two potentially related bugs that weren't fixed until 2012: http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/289541/ssms-open-table-w-binary-key-updates-too-many-rows http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/264592/ssms-deprecate-open-table ...there are many others... be afraid...

Comment: Your have more than one condition on the search. You will only see a record in your result set if **all** of those conditions are met.

Comment: Also see https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/14/bad-habits-to-kick-using-the-visual-designers.aspx for why you should learn DDL and DML instead of using the various visual designers in SSMS.

Comment: Can you post the schema?  What datatype is `Deleted`?  The assortment of faux boolean values is rather concerning: `0`, `1`, `'0'`, `'1'`, `'false'`, `'true'`.

Comment: @HABO:  It is a `bit` field, `not null`.  I don't know how to retrieve more info as to the values themselves.  I know that searching for `DELETED = 0` yields the proper results, but not `DELETED = 1` for some reason...

Comment: I also know that when I search specifically for the `DELETED` record, it says, `DELETED` is `True`.

Comment: There is no bug with BIT columns. I strongly recommend you stop using the visual designers altogether and you query the table instead of the view.

Comment: I see what the problem was; it's exactly what you guys were saying.  The `vw` prepending the table name stood for `view`.  Once I changed the table from using the `vwFiles_Attachments` to using the `Attachments` table, everything seems to work as it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to determine what's going on with your situation given the post and the comments.  I would try something like this to determine your Deleted column values:

```
SELECT DELETED, COUNT(*)
FROM vwFILES_ATTACHMENTS
GROUP BY DELETED
```

If that is returning you the correct results, then as dumb as it sounds, assuming Deleted = 1 does not work, try something like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM vwFILES_ATTACHMENTS
WHERE Deleted <> 0
```

If either = 1 or <> 0 work and return the correct row, then chances are @Joel was correct with his assumptions that other constraints in your WHERE clause are causing it not to return.  If = 1 or <> 0 do not work, then I'm clueless.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  The problem I was having was related to my using a `vw` or `view` table and not querying the table itself.  I commented above with more of an explanation.